# Calculating coefficients of generating functions from a relation.

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

> Given $B(z) = A(z)(1−z) \Leftrightarrow A(z) = B(z)(1 − z)$, derive an inversion formula for the coefficients $a_n$ of $A(z)$, and $b_n$ of $B(z)$.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n
  &= A(z) = B(z)(1-z) \\
  &= B(z) - zB(z) \\
  &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^{n+1}\\
  &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n-1} z^n
\end{split}
$$

Now can you say what $a_n$ looks like in terms of $b_n$? (Be careful with $a_0$).